# Is it possible to get count on different empid?

Tags: mysql

I have table name **tbl_stickering** on

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_stickering;
```

RESULT is:

[image]

But I want RESULT is :

[image]

I hope it is possible to get desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select empid and count(*) from the table and groupe the result by empid:

```
SELECT empid,COUNT(*) as Count of qstonesid
FROM tbl_stickering      
GROUP BY empid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

If you want stickering count of employee by date:

```
Select DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d'), empid, count(*) from tbl_stickering group  by DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d'), empid
```

If you want the stickering count of employees on a particular date:

```
Select empid, count(*) from tbl_stickering where DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%Y-%m-%d') = '2012-01-01' group by empid
```

Comment: Updated the andwer